# if/else no me funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cree un pequeño `script` que recorre unos `div`, revisa si estos comparten una de las **‪#‎id‬** que hay en el ‪**#‎array‬** y si es así agrega un `div` dentro.

Quiero hacer que si no cumple la regla el `div` desaparezca pero si uso `else{ $(this).remove()}` me borra todos los `div`.

Cuando uso `else{ $(this).addClass()` le aplica la clase a los que cumplen la 1 condición, no a los que no la cumple.
¿Saben por que puede ser?

```
var arreglo = ["A", "B", "c", "d","E","f","g","H"];
$(".sup > div").each(function(index){
    console.log("comprobación "+index)
   for(i=0; i< arreglo.length; i++ ){
      var id_ = $(this).attr("id") //obtiene la #id del div
      if(arreglo[i] === id_){//compara las #id si son iguales 
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+"        BINGO")//lo declara en la consola
        $(this).append("<div class='prueba'/>");//dibuja un div dentro
      } else if(arreglo[i] !== id_){
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+" NO")
        $(this).toggleClass("class")
      }
   }//for2
}/*function*/)
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iqudoblev/6v9hvza4/5/)

Comment: de momento lo resolvi asi
http://jsfiddle.net/iqudoblev/6v9hvza4/7/

si cumple agrega la clase ".a", si no la cumple ".b". como el script me cargaba las 2 clases si la cumplia la primera y solo la segunda si no lo cumplia. hice por css que 

.b{display:none}
.a.b{display:inherit}

si alguien tiene una solución mas elegante porfa que la ponga

Comment: Cuando decís  if(arreglo[i] === id_) el arreglo[i] e Id son del mismo tipo? no hay un int y double o float?. O Mejor dicho, Hace falta comprar los tipos? o vos queres saber si 2==2.00

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplificar bastante el código.
Para comprobar si un id existe en el array puedes utilizar el método some del objeto Array.
A partir de ahí, si existe le añades el div y si no le añades la clase para ocultarlo:

```js
var arreglo = ["A", "B", "c", "d","E","f","g","H"];
$(".sup > div").each(function(index){
  var $div = $(this);
  var id_ = $div.attr("id") //obtiene la #id del div
  if (arreglo.some(function(element) { return element===id_; })){
    $div.append("<div class='prueba' />");
  }
  else{
    $div.addClass("oculto");
  }
}/*function*/)
```

```css
.prueba{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background:purple;
  content:"Bingo";
}
.sup > div{
  margin:5px;
}
.sup > div.oculto{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sup">
   <div id="A">1</div>
   <div id="B">2</div>
   <div id="C">3</div>
   <div id="D">4</div>
   <div id="F">5</div>
   <div id="G">6</div>
   <div id="H">7</div>
   <div id="I">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si lo prefieres en lugar del método some podrías utilizar el findIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Las buenas prácticas de programación comienzan agregando `;` después de una línea de código. Puede que tu `if(){}` no funcione de manera correcta debido a esto.

```
var arreglo = ["A", "B", "c", "d","E","f","g","H"];
$(".sup > div").each(function(index){
    console.log("comprobación "+index);
   for(i=0; i< arreglo.length; i++ ){
      var id_ = $(this).attr("id"); //obtiene la #id del div
      if(arreglo[i] === id_){//compara las #id si son iguales 
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+"        BINGO");//lo declara en la consola
        $(this).append("<div class='prueba'/>");//dibuja un div dentro
      } else if(arreglo[i] !== id_){
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+" NO");
        $(this).toggleClass("class");
      }
   }//for2
}/*function*/)
```

Comment: Aunque tienes razón en que usar `;` es lo recomendado el hecho de que no funcionará el programa por esa causa no es cierto ya que el interprete de javascript agrega un `;` automaticamente al final de cada línea en caso que no sea especificado. Lee http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Además de los `;`, el problema lo solucioné con una variable que verifique si existe el id y lo compruebe fuera del `for` del arreglo:

```
var arreglo = ["A", "B", "c", "d","E","f","g","H"];

$(".sup > div").each(function(index){

    console.log("comprobación"+index);
  var existe;
  for(i=0; i< arreglo.length; i++ ){
      var id_ = $(this).attr("id"); //obtiene la #id del div
      existe = false;
      if(arreglo[i] === id_){//compara las #id si son iguales 
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+" BINGO");//lo declara en la consola
        $(this).append("<div class='prueba'/>");//dibuja un div dentro
        existe = true; // seteo la variable para corroborar que si existe el id 
        break; //me salgo del for
      }
   }//for2
   if(!existe)   { 
    $(this).remove(); 
   }else{
        console.log(arreglo[i]+" = "+id_+" NO");
   }
}/*function*/)
```